# spring and specs2 - caching context between tests

Tags: spring, scala, specs2

I am writing my first scala application using `specs2` and `spring-data-neo4j`. I wanted to write some integration test and for that I need loaded context (mainly for fetching repositories). The problem is that when I will put my tests in different specs files, context is loaded twice.

I was thinking if there is some way I can reuse already loaded context instance between tests. The first thing that came to my mind was to create an object in `test` classes that would hold context and then I would import it in every specs file, something like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

trait Neo4jSpringContext{
  val context = Neo4jSpringContext.context
}



object Neo4jSpringContext {
  val context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testNeo4jApplicationContext.xml")
}
```

and then just add `Neo4jSpringApplicationContext` trait to my specs classes, for example:

```
class CreateRetrieveSpringDataTest extends Specification with NoTimeConversions with Neo4jSpringContext
```

Now my question: is there any better way to do what I want (reuse Spring context between different specs files)?

Comment: caching state between tests is generally a really bad idea. Reusing a fixture (or Scope) that does the setup is much better.